# Realm taking too long to show objects in Table

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

Loading files with more columns takes Realm too long to load objects into the table. I've been using the TableLayout in here:
https://www.androidcode.ninja/android-scroll-table-fixed-header-column/.

TableLayout.java

```
    List<Fruits> oranges = new FruitsOranges().oranges();

         ...

    for(Fruits fruitOrange : this.oranges){

        TableRow tableRowForTableC = this.tableRowForTableC(fruitOrange);
        TableRow taleRowForTableD = this.taleRowForTableD(fruitOrange);

        tableRowForTableC.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        taleRowForTableD.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

        this.tableC.addView(tableRowForTableC);
        this.tableD.addView(taleRowForTableD);

    }
```

FruitsOranges.java

```
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults<Item> items = realm.where(Item.class)
            .findAllSorted(ItemFields.SQUARE.SQUARE_ID, Sort.DESCENDING);
   ...

// get the element data
            for (int iE = 0; iE < rowElementFruits.length - 4; iE++) {
                if(Integer.parseInt(rowId) == items.get(iE).getSquare().getSquareId())
                {
                    rowFruits[elementIndexPosition] = items.get(iE).getItem();
                    elementIndexPosition++;
                }
            }
            Fruits fruitOrange = new Fruits(rowFruits);
            oranges.add(fruitOrange);
```

I've placed some snippets of the code where I think the problem lies. I was planning to use pagination but since it's Realm, it didn't made sense. My goal is to add a file with 10,000 lines and load it instantly. Any suggestions to achieve this similarly is welcome.

Comment: For 10000 objects, you seem to be creating 10000 views instead of Recycling. This means that you should probably use a RecyclerView for this. Although considering it's a vertical AND horizontally scrollable recycler view with 2 fixed elements... writing this stuff takes about a week :D

Comment: Thank you! I really needed this comment in order to prove whats wrong with the code. They kept on forcing me to write upon the bad code they gave me. Any readings you can suggest?

Comment: Unfortunately the only thing that helped me back in the day with writing my own custom LayoutManager was reading through https://github.com/forceLain/AwesomeRecyclerView . It was 2 years ago, so it's super-hazy for me though. If your cell width does not vary in each row, then you have a simpler job to do than I did, though.

Comment: Much appreciated! Was even wondering if this can be fixed other than using RecycleView. Ill look into these. Thanks again buddy.

Comment: Only other option is creating your own custom view where you handle scrolls yourself and also do all the drawing yourself on a canvas by yourself, but I think that's equally tricky.